# MySQL + Android check if more value exists

Tags: java, android, mysql

i am currently using this code for the registration:

```
value1 = registerEmail.getText().toString();
    value2 = registerPassword.getText().toString();
    value3 = registerName.getText().toString();
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        Log.d("Connectc","executing check");
        ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user where email='"+value1+"'");
        while (res.next()) {
            userc = res.getString("email");
        }
            if (value1.equals(userc)) {
                tv.setText("Email already in use!");
            }
            else{
                Log.d("Connectc","registering");
                st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO user (email, password, name) VALUES('"+value1+"', '"+value2+"', '"+value3+"' )");
                tv.setText("Data is successfully saved." );
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LoginActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(i);
                finish();
                Log.d("Connectl","pfffffffff");
            }
```

Yes, it would be better using json, but i neet to use this... so the code check if the email exist, i also need to check if the username exist, how can i do? I have to add another sql query or i can edit this to check also if the username exist on db?
Thanks.

Comment: If you have email,username and password in same table then you can use only one querie.

Comment: can you help me with an example?

Comment: I can see you are already extracting everything from table `user`, so just extract username same way as you are getting string for `email` and cross check for `user`

Comment: SELECT * FROM user where email='email'with this query i put off all value related to the email, not?

Comment: Yes this querie will extract everything from user table where that mentioned `email` belongs, i.e. your username ans password.

Comment: OKay I think I got it what you want to say. If you want to check email and username already exist in DB then just run simple querie with or caluse somthing like this `SELECT * FROM user where email='email' or username = 'username'`

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the MySQL driver directly in your code.  I have had bad experiences with it.  You are better off creating a web service to do your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return row if email or username  exists so that you can prompt the user that login data already exists:

```
ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(
"SELECT * FROM user 
where email='"+value1+"' 
OR username='"+ value3+"'");
```

Comment: @vodich It will work but as user is inputting some values then its better to use prepared statement.

Comment: Yes I agree, Its always better to use prepared statement

Answer (score 1):

As you are taking input from user then better you use prepared statement. It will not allow you to insert any `SQL Injection`

```
value1 = registerEmail.getText().toString();
value3 = registerName.getText().toString();

query = "SELECT * FROM user where email=? OR username=? ";
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(query); // con is active connection
st.setText(1,value1);
st.setText(2,value3);
```

[How to use Prepared statement example.](http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/TwicePreparedStatement.shtml)

[What is SQL Injection?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)